# algorithm em : comprehension and example

Tags: algorithm, statistics, probability

I'm studying pattern recognition and I found an interesting algorithm that I'd like to deepen, the Expectations Maximization Algorithm. I haven't great knowledge of probability and statistics and I've read some article on the operation of the algorithm on normal or Gaussian distributions, but I would start with a simple example to understand better. I hope that the example may be suitable.

Assume we have a jar with 3 colors, red, green, blue. Corresponding probability of drawing each colored ball are: pr, pg, pb. Now, let's assume that we have the following parametrized model for the probabilities of drawing the different colours :

pr = 1/4

pg = 1/4 + p/4

pb = 1/2 - p/4

with p unknown parameter. Now assume that the man who is doing the experiment is actually colourblind and cannot discern the red from the green balls. He draws N balls, but only sees 
m1 = nR + nG red/green balls and m2 = nB blue balls.

The question is, can the man still estimate the parameter p and with that in hand calculate his best guess for the number of red and green balls (obviously, he knows the number of blue balls)? I think that obviously he can, but what about EM? What I have to consider?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think that you're right. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the general outline of the EM algorithm is that if you know the values of some of the parameters, then computing the MLE for the other parameters is very simple. The commonly-given example is mixture density estimation. If you know the mixture weights, then estimating the parameters for the individual densities is easy (M step). Then you go back a step: if you know the individual densities then you can estimate the mixture weights (E step). There isn't necessarily an EM algorithm for every problem, and even if there is one, it's not necessarily the most efficient algorithm. It is, however, usually simpler and therefore more convenient.

In the problem you stated, you can pretend that you know the numbers of red and green balls and then you can carry out ML estimation for `p` (M step). Then with the value of `p` you go back and estimate the numbers of red and green balls (E step). Without thinking about it too much, my guess is that you could reverse the roles of the parameters and still work it as an EM algorithm: you could pretend that you know `p` and carry out ML estimation for the numbers of balls, then go back and estimate `p`.

If you are still following, we can work out formulas for all this stuff.

Comment: I didn't understand. If p is the parameter to be estimated, how can we suppose to know it? Sorry for the ignorance but I don't follow your reasoning

Comment: @Fabrizio First you guess a value for `p`, then you update the other parameters. Then, given those estimates, you go back and compute a revised guess for `p`. Then you repeat those steps until the estimates change very little. It is a chicken and egg problem: if you know some of the parameters, it makes computing the others easy; but you don't really know them, so you have to go back and make new guesses, which changes the other parameters, etc ad infinitum. I believe the process is guaranteed to converge if there exists a local maximum of the likelihood function and we're close enough to it.

Comment: I'm thinking about this : one of the most important property of EM algorithm is that prob(x) at step i+1 is >= prob(x) at step i. In this way how can we ensure this?

Comment: I assume by prob(x) you mean the likelihood function prob(data | parameters). I believe Dempster, Laird, & Rubin proved that the likelihood is nondecreasing from one iteration to the next. If you can't find a reprint of their 1977 paper, I believe the argument is also stated by later commentators. I can't think of another reference at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

When "p" is not known, you can go for [maximum likihood or MLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood).

First, from your descriptions, "p" has to be in [-1, 2] or the probabilities will not make sense.

You have two certain observations: nG + nR = m and nB = N - m (m = m1, N = m1 + m2)

The chances of this happening is N! / (m! (N - m)!) (1- pb)^m (1 - pb)^(N - m).
Ignoring the constant of N choose m, we will maximize the second term:

p* = argmax over p of (1 - pb)^m pb^(N - m)

The easy solution is that p* should make pb = (N - m) / N = 1 - m / N.
So 0.5 - 0.25 p* = 1 = m / N ==> p* = max(-1, -2 + 4 * m / N)

Comment: so in this case we skip the E-step to get directly to the best solution p* ?

Comment: Well, the question is not MLE versus EM. If I'm not mistaken, the EM algorithm is in fact an algorithm to find the MLE; I think that was the main result of the Dempster, Laird, & Rubin paper, right? EM is useful because it is a way to find the MLE which is very convenient in some commonly encountered problems.